# passing GET variables in exception to rewrite rule in web.config

Tags: iis, web-config

I have a web.config file set up on an IIS box, which sends all web requests to a single index.php file, with two exceptions, which go to their intended destinations, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/app/Library/editor/$" ignoreCase="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/app/Library/editor$" ignoreCase="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/its/$" ignoreCase="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/its$" ignoreCase="true" />
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The exceptions work fine, in that http://servername/its, or http://servername/its/ serves up the correct page, but when there are parameters included in the request, eg, http://servernae/its/?value1=value2, it returns a page not found error.
I have a feeling that it is something obvious I have missed, but what do I need to add/change to get http://servernae/its/?value1=value2 to work as expected?

Regards

Comment: It is because you are appending the query string and there is no file path /index.php?value=1. There may be a path for index.php but iis or PHP request pipeline will look for a path with index.php + the query string that you have appended. Also if you plan to forward all requests, why do you need the conditions. Would not having ^(.*)$ be enough, a bit confused why you need the conditions. 
: )

Comment: Thank you for that, added another line including '/index.php' and it worked fine. The server hosts two supplementary apps in addition to the main one, hence the need for the exceptions.